# Can't call function from watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this method:

```
methods: {
    loop(data, outputArray) {
        data.forEach(function (element){
            if(Array.isArray(element)) {
                loop(element, outputArray);
            } else {
                outputArray.push(element);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

Now, I want to access this `loop` method from `watch` like that:

```
watch: {
    data(newData) {

        this.images = [];
        let sliderImages = [];

        if( newData.image_link ) {
            if( Array.isArray( newData.image_link ) ) {
                sliderImages = [...sliderImages, ...newData.image_link];
            } else {
                sliderImages.push( newData.image_link )
            }
        }

        if( newData.additional_image_link ) {
            if( Array.isArray( newData.additional_image_link ) ) {
                sliderImages = [...sliderImages, ...newData.additional_image_link];
            } else {
                sliderImages.push( newData.additional_image_link )
            }
        }

        if( Array.isArray(sliderImages) ) {
            sliderImages.forEach( ( item, index ) => {
                this.images.push({
                    id : index,
                    big : item,
                    thumb : item
                });
            });
        } else {
            this.images.push({
                id : 0,
                big : newData.image_link,
                thumb : newData.image_link,
            });
        }
        
        this.Recursive(newData);
        this.loop( sliderImages, this.flattened )
    },
},
```

But everytime I got this error message:

> Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "data": "ReferenceError: loop
> is not defined"

Comment: There are several problems with your code. First of all, you can't watch `data`  - unless you have a `computed` or `data` member actually named `data` (e.g: `data: () => ({ data: [] })`). Secondly, in your `loop` method you are calling a `loop` function, which is not defined. You probably want to call `this.loop` but, before you could do that, you have to make the `forEach` function an arrow function (otherwise `this` will be its internal context, not the component instance).
My suggestion is you give a broader context and explain what want to achieve. I guarantee it can be done simpler.

Comment: Last, but not least, the `loop` method doesn't need to be a `method`. By looking at its functionality I say it could (perhaps should) be a static function, imported here. Basically a helper function. You don't need to redefine it for every new instance of this component. If you need help simplifying your code, consider providing the input data and a clearly stated end goal (the outcome/output).

Comment: @tao I have `data` props and now I am using arrow function. It seems working.

Comment: Right, if you have a `data` prop, watching it makes sense. My first thought was you're attempting to watch the `data()` function from Options API, which is mainly a reactivity setup for component state props (and `this.data` doesn't point to it). I'm glad you found my comments useful. If you think the solution might help others in the future, consider posting it as an answer. If not, consider removing the question. In current form the question is not very useful (needs more context and details before it could be turned into a *runnable* [mcve]).